# How to transform an element in a page using css3 transforms?

Tags: css

i got a div that looks like this:

```
+---------+
|         |
+---------+
```

and I want to transform it like this:

```
  +---------+
 /           \
+-------------+
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Do you want to change the perspective too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "how to transform" you mean how to rotate on the x axis applying a perspective to achieve deepness, then you can do it by using CSS3 `transform`'s `perspective` and `rotate3d`:

<kbd>[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/NU3NH/1/)</kbd>

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    Hover me    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: silver;
    font-size: 4em;
    margin: 100px;
}

.box:hover{
    transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 50deg);
}
```

You may wanna [read this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19789989/1654265) too.

Comment: god bless you man ... that's exactly what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use CSS transforms, [**see here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tyCs4/1/)

HTML

```
<div class='trapezoid'></div>
```

CSS

```
.trapezoid {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 3em;
  /**outline: solid 1px;/**/
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.trapezoid:before {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  content: '';
}
.trapezoid:before {
  width: 20em; height: 3em;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.142em, -2.6em);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.142em, -2.6em);
}
```

For a simpler implementation, [**see this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzpud/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    margin-top:30px;   
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You haven't used CSS3 transform.

Comment: The OP asked to transform it, not for the specific use of transform.

Comment: It's in the question: "How to transform an element in a page **using css3 transforms**?". But I agree with your static CSS method.

Comment: Updated with a more complex way of achieving the same, with the use of transform :)

Comment: Can't argue with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Divs are square elements, so you can't transform the actual bounding box of the div to be trapezoidal. However, you can play with borders and box shadows to achieve visual effects like that. See [CSS3 matrix3d rectangle to trapezoid transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954778/css3-matrix3d-rectangle-to-trapezoid-transformation) for some potential help.