# Stretch an image to a quadrilateral in canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

Is it possible to draw an image to an arbitrary quadrilateral in the canvas 2d API?

I see drawImage lets me draw to a rectangle.

```
ctx.drawImage(someImage, x, y, width, height);
```

and rotate lets me rotate it.

```
ctx.rotate(angle);
ctx.drawImage(someImage, ...);
```

But is it possible to choose an arbitrary 4 points to map the original 4 points of the image rectangle too?

```
drawImageTo4Points(
  image,
  topLeftX, topLeftY,          // location to place the topLeft of the image
  topRightX, topRightY,        // location to place the topRight of the image
  bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY,    // location to place the bottomLeft of the image
  bottomRightX, bottomRightY); // location to place the bottomRight of the image
```

Comment: It's possible to map a rectangular image to an arbitrary parallelogram, but the only ways I know of to map it to any other quadrilateral would require using a loop to draw pixels or stripes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to skew image like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426887/how-to-skew-image-like-this)