# Android Linear mapping of images

Tags: android, 3d, linear-algebra

I'm looking to map an `ImageView` drawing rect to a quadrilateral.

I was hoping I could do this by overriding `ViewGroup.getChildStaticTransformation (View child, Transformation t)` and messing around with the [`Matrix`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) with and without a `Camera`, but its not as simple as I would like.

I want be able to take a bitmap and project it onto a 3d plane / surface.

I thought I had found a nice and easy solution with [Matrix.setRectToRect(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit%29) but not quite there. As `RectF` only allows the edges to be specified rather than the corners I cannot use to map to a trapezium. I would like to just be able to specify my destination shape rather than mess around with 3D animation classes or manually rotating a `Camera`.

I know i need to brush up on my Linear Algebra but I'm hoping someone can give me some pointers :)

Thanks!

EDIT: looking around I see I want to use a [Projective Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_transformation)

EDIT: I'm going to test out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484071/how-do-i-compete-the-transformation-matrix-needed-to-transform-a-rectangle-into)

Comment: if you need to map something like human faces i suggest to use OpenCV, but in general i don't get your question as it's written right now.

Comment: Sorry I must not have explained myself very well, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Doh, its [Matrix.setPolyToPoly()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setPolyToPoly%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) that i was looking for! It was there the whole time, since API level 1 (thank god!)