# Tutorial on placing a 3D cube on a GWT Canvas

Tags: gwt, java-3d

Could someone point me to a tutorial on putting a cube on a GWT Canvas? I only have one sample code with Context2d and Canvas and one sample with SimpleUniverse. The latter I don't know how to integrate into a GWT application. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you [can use WebGL in your browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl), then have a look at [http://gwt-g3d.appspot.com/](http://gwt-g3d.appspot.com/)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Could you please use this as an answer as well so I can mark it as solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For browsers that support WebGL (not Internet Explorer, not even IE 10) (http://caniuse.com/#feat=webgl), you can use [gwt-g3d](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-g3d/).

For non-WebGL browsers, you could either perform a perspective projection yourself (it's actually not very hard if you have the coordinates of your cube, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2484154/291741), or maybe there's already a GWT (or GWT compatible) library for non-WebGL 3D I don't know about yet.

Comment: Thank you, GWT-G3D seems to be just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Some non-WebGL samples is here https://code.google.com/p/w3dgwt/